# remove www from web address

Tags: web, iis-8

I'm running php on IIS 8.0.

when I enter the site address with **www** server returns IIS Error 500. with out **www** everything is OK.

How can I automatically remove **www** from adress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use url rewrite module

add this code to **web.config** and replace **domain.tld** with your domain name

`<rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.tld{PATH_INFO}" />
</rule>`

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to redirect your site to domain only,
1) using DNS server, in DNS you can redirect your visitors to domain only,
2) using IIS config file -> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config.

Comment: Look into a module for IIS called URL Rewrite, this module will let you create a  301 redirect in your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to simply redirect because you will have to do that for every page and subdomain. My code will auto strip the www. for you.

.htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

If you want to fix you DNS issue just add a 'A' record with www.yourwebsite.com